# Using variable names where single quotes are expected

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

This is the Google RankTracker found [here](http://www.blindfiveyearold.com/new-ways-to-track-keyword-rank)

```
<script>
if (document.referrer.match(/google\.com/gi) && document.referrer.match(/cd/gi)) {
  var myString = document.referrer;
  var r        = myString.match(/cd=(.*?)&/);
  var rank     = parseInt(r[1]);
  var kw       = myString.match(/q=(.*?)&/);
  if (kw[1].length > 0) {
    var keyWord  = decodeURI(kw[1]);
  } else {
    keyWord = "(not provided)";
  }
  var p        = document.location.pathname;
  ga('send', 'event', 'RankTracker', keyWord, p, rank, {'nonInteraction': 1});
  dataLayer.push({'eventCategory':'RankTracker','eventAction':keyWord,'eventLabel':p,'eventValue':rank 'event':'RankTracker'});
}
</script>
```

I'm trying to get this working with Google Tag Manager, (the `dataLayer.push({...` section at the bottom), but I'm not sure the variables are working (although they work with the Universal Analytics `ga('send'...)` portion

Should calling the variables as I have done work in this case?

My main concern is the lack of single quotes around the values

BTW, if anyone is wondering I have set up macros in GTM for eventCategory, etc., and my rule for firing is that event is equal to RankTracker

Comment: Where exactly are single quotes expected?

Comment: Hi, e.g. `'eventAction':'actual keyword would be here'`

Answer (score 1):

> Should calling the variables as I have done work in this case?
>
> My main concern is the lack of single quotes around the values

Assuming you mean the `keyword`, `p`, and `rank` values used on the right-hand side of the `:` in a property initializer, those are used correctly and do not need quotes.

Here's a simpler example:

```
var foo = "testing";
var obj = {prop: foo};
console.log(obj.prop); // "testing"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Google RankTracker, but I do know you need a comma between those these two key/value pairs.

```
'eventValue':rank 'event':'RankTracker'
```

should be

```
'eventValue':rank, 'event':'RankTracker'
```

Maybe that's what's causing unexpected results.